# Select and Disable Features in Feature Tree Dialog in Installshield

Tags: windows-installer, installshield-2011, installscript-msi

I have created an Installer using Installscript msi. I perform a custom installation installing only selective features.
Now during the Maintenance Install, when I chose the Installation type to be "Custom', all features installed as part of fresh Installation (first time install) appear to be selected in the feature tree. 
I dont want the user to be able to deselect these features. Instead, I want these featured/sub features to appear as selected and grayed out.
Basically user should not be able to remove any feature/subfeature selected during fresh install.
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer doesn't support this scenario. Maintenance install is meant to allow the user to remove or add features.